# managing memory in a for loop

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to save information from a file to structs in the heap.
The problem is: if i print out the information in the for loop where i save the data, it works well, but when i print out the data outside that for loop i get only garbage
i wanna know why :( probably i am doing a bad work with the malloc

i could work inside the first for loop but i want to know what i am doing wrong

```
typedef struct{
    int tipoDeCodificacion;
    void* carta;
}pedido;

typedef struct{
    void* nombre;
    void* regalo;
}regalos;
void creacionRegalos(FILE *cartas){ 
    FILE *final=fopen("regalos.txt","w");
    int cantidadCartas, i;
    fscanf(cartas,"%d\n",&cantidadCartas);
    printf("%d\n",cantidadCartas);

    pedido *Pedidos=(pedido *)malloc(sizeof(cantidadCartas));
    regalos **Regalos=malloc(sizeof(regalos *)*cantidadCartas);
    for(i=0;i<cantidadCartas;i++){
        char *lineaCodificada=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        int *tipo=malloc(sizeof(int));
        fscanf(cartas,"%d\n",tipo);

        Pedidos[i].tipoDeCodificacion=*tipo;
        printf("%d\n",Pedidos[i].tipoDeCodificacion); //this print works well
        fgets(lineaCodificada,100,cartas);
        Pedidos[i].carta=lineaCodificada;
        puts(Pedidos[i].carta); //this print works well
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cantidadCartas; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",Pedidos[i].tipoDeCodificacion); //just prints garbage
        printf("%s\n",(char *)Pedidos[i].carta);//prints garbage
    }
}
```

Comment: `tipoDeCodificacion` has type `int` but you are assigning `tipo` which is type `int *`.  This should have given an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
pedido *Pedidos=(pedido *)malloc(sizeof(cantidadCartas));
```

is invalid. You are allocating memory for `sizeof(int)` bytes. You should:

```
pedido *Pedidos=(pedido *)malloc(sizeof(*Pedidos) * cantidadCartas);
```

allocate memory for `contidadCartas` count of `pedido` structures. The time you access `Pedidos` memory using `pedido*` pointer you do undefined behavior.

Your code is really hard to read, badly indented, with strange locale names, no error checking and it leaks memory for all `malloc` you call. A good code would check all error places `if (Pedidos == NULL) { handle_error(); }`  and `if(fscanf("%d", ....) != 1)` etc. The allocation of `int *typo = malloc(sizeof(int));` straight up leaks memory - it is nowhere `free`d. I also strongly encourage you to write all code, including all structure, variables and function names in english.

Comment: So he's writing off the end of the array, and the first print just unfortunately happens to work? (sorry, I'm learning C and trying to learn from this mistake).

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It may work. All code may work. It may not. It may format your hard drive. It may spawn dragons in your room. You don't know. No one knows. Because you cannot place any requirements on the code with undefined behavior. So you don't know. I believe it just so happens that `malloc` allocates the memory for `Regalos` continuously, so it just happens to work.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it's undefined behavior caused by going off the end of an array?

Comment: There is no array. It is just memory. It is accessing the memory outside of bounds. So it would be referencing an object beyond valid memory. The expression `Pedidos[0]` is just `*(Pedidos + 0)` which is just `*Pedidos`.

Comment: Bro i love you, it just was a silly error hahaha sorry for the awful code

Comment: ```pedido *Pedidos=(pedido *)malloc(sizeof(pedido)*cantidadCartas);``` is the correct line

Comment: It's the same. `sizeof(pedido)` and `sizeof(*Pedidos)` is the same.